# Sort Order In OpportunityLineItem Preview

Tags: apex, visualforce, sort, quotelineitem

We have Sort button in `OpportunityLineItem`. Using this, customer may able to sort the products in the order they want, but in Preview (Visualforce page preview) it's  dispaying default order (Ascending by product name) not in the order customer sort. I used SortOrder in `ORDER BY` but still  I am not getting the order correctly. Here is my query in controller.

```
Oli= [Select
         ID, OpportunityId, Description, Opportunity.Reactive_Sheet__c,
         Opportunity.Service_Sheet__c, Service_Sheet__r.name, Maintenance_Reactive_Sheet__r.name,
         Quantity, Product2.name, Maintenance_Reactive_Sheet__c, Service_Sheet__c, 
         Product2.Stock_Unit__c, UnitPrice, TotalPrice, Opportunity.VAT_Rate__c, 
         Service_Sheet__r.Visit__r.Asset__r.Name,
         Show_Description__c, Line_Item_Description__c, Product2.Extended_Sales_Description__c,
         Product2.Sales_Description__c
     From OpportunityLineitem 
     Where OpportunityId =:Delnoteid 
     Order By SortOrder];
```

`Delnoteid` = the current Opportunity Id.

I am using this controller in Visualforce component and surprisingly my **Query runs twice** .In first run Query returns default order (by product name).In second run query I have the correct order (in which the customer sort i.e the condition given in query works) but my page uses first time run query so it display default order instead of sort order.

Comment: Providing additional details would help. Do you have a Visualforce page that you're using to display the `OpportunityLineItem` records? If so, it would help if you were to [edit] your question to include the code for the Visualforce page as well. Also, where are you getting `SortOrder` from?  If you want to allow people to sort by both `ASC` (ascending) and `DESC` (descending) orders, you'll probably need to move to dynamic SOQL.

Comment: When you say "We have Sort button in OpportunityLineItem" do you mean you have the standard button on the layout or do you mean that you created a custom button?

Answer (score 0):

(Amended my response to an actual answer, given that I am not allowed to ask questions yet).

Given your statement about 2 queries being run, I suspect you are not rerendering the apex fragment after requerying.

IF your requery is triggered from the UI, such as via a `commandButton`, you could do something like this:

Your page:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="line-items">
...
</apex:pageBlockTable>


<apex:commandButton ...... action="{!queryOpportunityLineItems}" rerender="line-items"/>
```

Your controller method:

```
public void queryOpportunityLineItems(){
    // your query logic here
}
```

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment on the question, rather than an answer (because it doesn't really answer the question), so I'll be flagging this. I think you need 50 reputation before you're allowed to comment on other people's questions and answers. One way to get up to that amount of repuation without asking/answering questions is to help by editing questions to improve formatting or correct spelling/grammar issues (which I think you can do right away).

Comment: I have edited my questions see the updated question above.

Comment: edited to be a response @DerekF

Comment: @SankarGanesh did the above work?